# Cannot compile when trying to utilize boost::asio::signal_set

Tags: c++, mingw, boost-asio

I'm using MinGW 4.5.1 for compiling a client application (C++, Windows XP) utilizing the newest version of Boost 1_47.  For some reason that I can't seem to determine, when I go to compile using the `boost::asio::signal_set` type I get a compile error (`boost::asio::signal_set` does not define a type), and when trying to explicitly include either of the associated signal_set headers, I get complaints of no file can be found (despite the file indeed being where expected).  I have tried including files within the same level of the directory tree without issue, it only seems to hang on the `signal_set.hpp` file (although no complaints when using the full header asio.hpp which has it as an include).  I get the same behavior when trying to use boost 1_46_1 as well.

Might anyone have any insights as to what is going on?

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces the problem so we can try. I have no trouble using Asio from boost 1.47 on my mac.

Comment: After some investigation I realized I had incorrectly pointed to the the boost includes with my Eclipse workspace, which when preparing a snippet of code to reproduce the problem I discovered.  I'm surprised this didn't have ramifications elsewhere but things appear to be working now.  Seems like I was indirectly helped by you Sam, thanks. CTC

Comment: please post an answer to your own question, that way other users who search for this problem will know the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The issue I had was that I was not properly including the boost headers as I thought I was.  Usually I have the boost installation in some directory on the hard drive, say C:\Boost\some_boost_version.  Whereas I thought I was pointing to the new boost version's includes at C:\Boost\boost-1_47\boost, there was not a level inside the directory tree for \boost, everything was in C:\Boost\boost-1_47.  By adding a new directory (created C:\Boost\boost-1_47\boost) and putting the includes within that, my problem was resolved.  Something I overlooked when I retooled my build scripts for build the boost libraries on my machine.