# error: ‘signal_set’ in namespace ‘boost::asio’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, boost-asio

I'm working on the first HTTP server example of the Boost::asio library v1.47.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

And I got this message at compilation with gcc version 4.5.2 :

> error: ‘signal_set’ in namespace ‘boost::asio’ does not name a type

I use Jam, with this jamfile :

```
C++ = g++ ;
LINK = $(C++) ;
LINKLIBS = -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt ;
Main node : main.cpp server.cpp reply.cpp request_handler.cpp request_parser.cpp connection.cpp connection_manager.cpp ;
```

I think the code is correct because I got the error from the beginning, without modifying the example source, I just commented the line to resolve the problem previously.
But now, I need signals.

So I think I messed something up with my Jamfile.

I found this other question related to mine, bt it didn't helped me :
[Cannot compile when trying to utilize boost::asio::signal_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764611/cannot-compile-when-trying-to-utilize-boostasiosignal-set)

**Edit :**
In fact I figured out :
Ubuntu which I am using provide only the version 1.42 of boost, and boost::asio::signals wern't implemented yet ...
I installed the latest version, and now everything is fine.

Comment: Voting to close since the OP figured out their issue.

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that the *compiler* does not recognize the identifier. This is a common situation when you forget to include a header, or if the version of your header is different and does not contain that identifier.

Is that the first error that the compiler is producing? In particular, has it complained that it cannot locate any header? That could indicate that the headers are not in the path that the compiler is checking in which case you might want to add a `-Ipath_to_boost` flag to the compile line.

It would also be interesting if you can produce what actual file is being compiled when that error is encountered.